# tool to test ICE/STUN/TURN protocol under WebRTC step by step?

Tags: webrtc, stun, turn

I want to study relations of ICE/STUN/TURN protocol and network packets under operation of WebRTC. I found many testing products. Because I want to observe ICE/STUN/TURN mode of operation step by step, those testing products can not help me. I want to found a tool like pjsip icedemo tool (http://www.pjsip.org/pjnath/docs/html/ice_demo_sample.htm ).Have anyone used that tool?

Comment: FF (about-webrtc) & Chrome (chrome://webrtc-internals) are useful to see the state of ICE candidates and communication steps. For further details you would need wireshark traces.

Answer (score 0):

I think that best test tools are Firefox and Chrome.
Turn on the logs for WebRTC and ICE and you will able to see all the details.